# xsl:for-each repeating the first row

Tags: xslt, foreach

i left out the for-each end statements in previous post: here is a snap shot of the doc and the xsl including the end stmts. i made a change to code (removed the inline "`<for-each end>`" which changed the results. Now, there are two answers for each question BUT the first row is no longer repeated.
Document:
for-each-groupEXAM_QSTN_TXT
for-eachEXAM_ANSWR_TXT end end

BI Pub xsl dialog boxes:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//row" group-adjacent="EXAM_QSTN_RECID">
<?for-each:current-group()?><?EXAM_ANSWR_TXT?>
<?end for-each?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

New Result:
Test question text
TrueTrue
FalseFalse

/*****************************************************************/
Creating a template using Word w/BI Publisher. New to xsl code. Within a for-each-group, i have a for-each loop that is erroneously repeating the first row. Each record has the group value AND the child value. Data consists of each record containing: an exam question and answer text (with 2 - 4 "rows" as possible answers). The first "row" is used as the "exam question txt" in the for-each-group. The first row is ALSO the "first possible answer" in the for-each loop. Problem: the first (row) which is a possible answer is repeated at the end of the loop so template shows 5 possible answers not 4 (or in the example below 3 instead of 2 possible). Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here's the code:

`<xsl:for-each-group select=".//row" group-adjacent="EXAM_QSTN_RECID">`

```
<?for-each:current-group()?><?EXAM_ANSWR_TXT?><?end for-each?>
```

output:
True False question text
True
False
True

XML Word generated code:

```
    <w:textInput>
<w:default w:val="for-each-group"/>
</w:textInput>
</w:ffData>
</w:fldChar>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> FORMTEXT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>for-each-group</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
<w:ffData>
<w:name w:val="Text1"/>
<w:enabled/>
<w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
<w:statusText w:type="text" w:val="<?ref:xdo0018?>"/>
<w:textInput>
<w:default w:val="EXAM_QSTN_TXT"/>
</w:textInput>
</w:ffData>
</w:fldChar>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:instrText>FORMTEXT</w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>EXAM_QSTN_TXT</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="Text5"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
<w:ffData>
<w:name w:val="Text5"/>
<w:enabled/>
<w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
<w:statusText w:type="text" w:val="<?ref:xdo0006?>"/>
<w:textInput>
<w:default w:val="for-each"/>
</w:textInput>
</w:ffData>
</w:fldChar>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> FORMTEXT </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>for-each</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00887F5C">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
<w:ffData>
<w:name w:val="Text1"/>
<w:enabled/>
<w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
<w:statusText w:type="text" w:val="<?ref:xdo0019?>"/>
<w:textInput>
<w:default w:val="EXAM_ANSWR_TXT"/>
</w:textInput>
</w:ffData>
</w:fldChar>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:instrText>FORMTEXT</w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:noProof/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>EXAM_ANSWR_TXT</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00360D93">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
<w:bookmarkStart w:id="2" w:name="Text2"/>
<w:r>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
<w:sz w:val="24"/>
<w:szCs w:val="24"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin">
<w:ffData>
<w:name w:val="Text2"/>
<w:enabled/>
<w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
<w:statusText w:type="text" w:val="<?ref:xdo0001?>"/>
<w:textInput>
<w:default w:val="end"/>
</w:textInput>
</w:ffData>
</w:fldChar>
</w:r>
<w:r>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: it's all there in the question, code, description of input and sample output.  is there something else you need ?

Comment: Please read the link more carefully. *Reproducible* means I can take your input example (which doesn't exist at all) and run it against your code (which is a mere snippet) and get the result you complain about. Without having to add anything.

Comment: For XSLT questions, in the body of your post (not images) we need a sample XML (well-formed, rules-compliant markup) and a full XSLT (not line snippets) which by themselves should *reproduce* your error or undesired result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the xslt in the original post is all there is. it's a word doc with two fields each have a BI Pub dialog box with only that code in them.

Comment: I suggest first try to understand what wellformed Xml means. Your code snippet handles row’s that are not in your ms-word xml . So probably this snippet is meant for  a next transformation or mode.

Comment: thank you all - am convinced that your thinking on it and the mind-meld helped the answers arrive. 

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: XSL in Word w/BI Publisher:
Document:
for-each-group EXAM_QSTN_TXT
for-each EXAM_ANSWR_TXT end end

BI Pub dialog box for code:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select=".//row" group-adjacent="EXAM_QSTN_RECID">
<?for-each-group:current-group();./EXAM_ANSWR_RECID?>
<?end for-each-group?>
<?end for-each-group?>
```

Produces:
Test Question Text
multiple choice answer 1
multiple choice answer 2
etc.